# Telegram Bot api using SOCKS5

Tags: telegram-bot, socks

I'm using Telegram Bot class library authored by RoundRobin, because of censorship and internet filtering it is a little bit hard to write and work with Telegram Bots. is it any direct way to use this API using SOCKS5? either for sending or listening to messages.